# WMI query returns nothing

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query

I am making a query with WMI to check for a particular drive letter, if it does not exist then I want to run a method that will create it with specific settings. Now the problem I am facing is when I send a test query to see if the drive letter exists, it returns empty. No error or exception.

How would I handle this type of situation?

Thanks

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                      new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\cimv2",
                      @"SELECT * FROM Win32_Volume Where DriveLetter = '" + DriveLetter + "'");
                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    drives.CurrentDriveLetter = queryObj["DriveLetter"] == null ? "null" : queryObj["DriveLetter"].ToString();
                    drives.CurrentDriveSize = queryObj["Capacity"] == null ? "null" : queryObj["Capacity"].ToString();
                    drives.CurrentDriveName = queryObj["Label"] == null ? "null" : queryObj["Label"].ToString();


                }
```

Comment: what is the `UpdateUI(drives) can you post that method as well..? also what is `drives and where is it declared.?`

Comment: drives is a class, just holds number/letter/label/size. UpdateUI is what updates the listview. Those 2 things can be ignored, what I am trying to figure out is a way to distinguish between a result WITH data and from results WITHOUT data. This is the tricky part for me since no exception is thrown

Comment: I tested the code and I get everything but the drive Letter also your `.ToString()` should be casted this way `(string)queryObj["DriveLetter"];`

Comment: you can look at this link and easily convert over to C# code as well http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394592(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: but what if that drive doesn't exists? Try passing in a random drive letter and it will not error out so you have no idea if the query was valid or not

Comment: I figured your issue out ..you need to do one this twice keep the code you have and remove the `DriveName` and use the code that i am going to post to return the actual `DriveLetter` ok

Comment: you need to do some additional checks if there there is a difference between the object["DriveLetter"] for example existing and the value returning null.. so you need to do a check for null just because you use `queryObj["DriveLetter"] == null ? "null" : queryObj["DriveLetter"].ToString();` that only assigns the value `null` if null otherwise it returns the `drive letter` that line will never generate an error unless the object you are trying to reference does not exist..

Comment: for example run the code `var mosNew = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk");` and try to add `Console.WriteLine(mo["DriveLetter"]` it will Error because the Drive Letter should be the name when Selecting from `Wind32_LogicalDisk`

Answer (score 2):

Following your comments you only need determine if the collection returned by the [`ManagementObjectSearcher.Get`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67a77ef1.aspx) method has elements. For that you can use the [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectcollection.count.aspx) property.

Try this sample code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;

namespace GetWMI_Info
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementScope Scope;                
                Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", "."), null);
                Scope.Connect();
                ObjectQuery Query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Volume Where DriveLetter='X:' ");
                ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, Query);
                if (Searcher.Get().Count==0)                
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Do something, when the collection is empty.");                
                }
                else
                foreach (ManagementObject WmiObject in Searcher.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}","Name",WmiObject["Name"]);// String

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Exception {0} Trace {1}",e.Message,e.StackTrace));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```